# Question about package 'dtw' in R

Tags: r, pattern-recognition

Please see below images. Using package 'dtw' in R, is there a way to ensure that pattern 1) has a lower computed distance relative to the reference pattern than pattern 2) does. In other words, can one weight observations that are more recent (further to the right in time) as being more important for distance computation? You will notice the two patterns 1) and 2) below are meant to look identical with the exception of the placement of the part of the time series that is meant to look like the reference pattern.

[image: test and query images]